# add a list to another list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with a problem with a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': [[{'zone':'A', 'number':'7'}, {'zone':'B', 'number': '8'}], 
                                   [{'zone':'A', 'number':'6'}, {'zone':'E', 'number':'7'}]],
                       'column_B': [[{'zone':'C', 'number':'4'}], [{'zone':'D', 'number': '9'}]]})
```

###### I want to insert column_B into the column_A list so the output of the first line of column_A has to be:

```py
[{'zone':'A', 'number':'7'}, {'zone':'B', 'number': '8'}, {'zone':'C', 'number':'4'}]
```

Probably is the easiest thing, I can imagine, but I find so many errors with functions like insert and the '+' command and I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest is join lists by `+`:

```
df['column_A'] = df['column_A'] + df['column_B']
print (df)
                                            column_A  \
0  [{'zone': 'A', 'number': '7'}, {'zone': 'B', '...   
1  [{'zone': 'A', 'number': '6'}, {'zone': 'E', '...   

                         column_B  
0  [{'zone': 'C', 'number': '4'}]  
1  [{'zone': 'D', 'number': '9'}]
```

Data are different, seems in second column are not lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': [[{'zone':'A', 'number':'7'}, {'zone':'B', 'number': '8'}], 
                               [{'zone':'A', 'number':'6'}, {'zone':'E', 'number':'7'}]],
                   'column_B': [{'zone':'C', 'number':'4'}, {'zone':'D', 'number': '9'}]})

df['column_A'] = df['column_A'] + df['column_B'].apply(lambda x: [x])
print (df)
                                            column_A  \
0  [{'zone': 'A', 'number': '7'}, {'zone': 'B', '...   
1  [{'zone': 'A', 'number': '6'}, {'zone': 'E', '...   

                       column_B  
0  {'zone': 'C', 'number': '4'}  
1  {'zone': 'D', 'number': '9'}
```

Comment: probably i have not the same type of columns in the real problem, in the real problem it return me a "type error: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list", so I have to convert to list, then join them and last convert again to a dict?

Comment: what is `print (df['column_A'].iat[0])` and  `print (df['column_B'].iat[0])` in real data?

Comment: it returns me the same type of output as fake data

Comment: @MarioFernandez - so it means working? If not working problem is in real data

Comment: Yes i think the problem is column B in real data is not a dictionary, so i will try to change the type of data